# Angular: observables are not streams

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm confused by the following statement.

"*One important thing to bear in mind is that observables are not streams, those are two different concepts*"

When we define Observable, we would certainly talk about streams. Could someone shed some light on this?

How is Angular using both these concepts?

Comment: Where does this sentence come from by the way?

Comment: Probably it meas that it is not equal to the streams as in Java or other lang, where you can manage the memory usage by dividing it in streams. 
Just read the doc of rxjs and take a look on [marble diagrams](http://rxmarbles.com/) of observables to see their behavior

Comment: @martin https://medium.com/@tkssharma/reactive-programming-rx-js-introduction-32bf963eee1b

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, Streams are water pipes and Observables are the taps that connected to the water pipes. Those taps can have multiple outlets and can help emitting water to other pipes or buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Observables are how you interact with streams.

From the same article your statement is from:

> This combination of a stream with a set of functional operators to
>   transform streams leads us to the notion of Observable. Think of it as
>   your API for tapping into a stream.

Source: https://medium.com/@tkssharma/reactive-programming-rx-js-introduction-32bf963eee1b